# do while loop exit base on condition being specify

Tags: java

In my code, I want the loop to exit if the user enters an empty string for either variables. Nothing seems to work after I enter an empty string.

Where am I going wrong?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String lakeName;
        String timeRun;

        HashMap<String, Double> newMap = new HashMap<>();

        do {
            System.out.println("Enter the Lake Name");
            lakeName = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter number of minutes run");
            timeRun = input.nextLine();
            Double finalRun = Double.parseDouble(timeRun);
            newMap.put(lakeName, finalRun);

            if(lakeName.equalsIgnoreCase("") || timeRun.equalsIgnoreCase("")){

                break;
            }

        } while(true);

        for(String key: newMap.keySet()){
            Double value = newMap.get(key);
            System.out.println(key + ": "+ value);
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try this :

```
 do {
    System.out.println("Enter the Lake Name");
    lakeName = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter number of minutes run");
    timeRun = input.nextLine();
    if(lakeName.equalsIgnoreCase("") || timeRun.equalsIgnoreCase("")){

        break;
    }
    Double finalRun = Double.parseDouble(timeRun);
    newMap.put(lakeName, finalRun);



} while(true);
```

put the `if{...}` up, if not , it will be given NumberFormatException.

Comment: Thank you so much! this seem to work! I greatly appreciate your help. Can you please tell me why mine wasn't working as expected?

Comment: your code did`t run before throws Exception. there are many situations~

Comment: In general always check user input, you never know what you might be given.  In this case before  working with the input you'll want to validate it and exit the loop if it is not what you are expecting.  This is more or less what website forms do, first the validate the user's input and then they send it off for processing.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do is to check if String is [isEmpty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29), put a `break` statement.

So in your case it would be like:

```
if(lakeName.isEmpty())
   break;
```

You gotto do the same thing with `timeRun` variable;

Comment: Thanks for your response but lakeName.isEmty() or timeRun.isEmpty doesn't seem to work at all. I am new to java so please don't get mad at me:)

Comment: @Intelligent did you put this statement after reading the input lakeName = input.nextLine(); right?

Comment: I did this but it doesn't seem to work.   if(lakeName.isEmpty( )){

                break;
            }

            if(timeRun.isEmpty( )){
                break;
            }

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help. You are awesome.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I am new on this site.

Answer (score 2):

When you enter an empty string for the `timeRun`, you will try to parse an empty string as double. This fails and throws this exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
```

You can solve this by placing the following code into the loop:

```
        System.out.println("Enter the Lake Name");
        lakeName = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter number of minutes run");
        timeRun = input.nextLine();
        if (lakeName.equalsIgnoreCase("") || timeRun.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            break;
        }
        Double finalRun = Double.parseDouble(timeRun);
        newMap.put(lakeName, finalRun);
```

I just moved the `break` up a few lines, including its condition.

Also, you can replace the `.equalsIgnoreCase("")` by `.isEmpty()`, as already stated in the other answer.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help.

Comment: You are welcome. Also, since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you might be interested in [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), which introduces you to how Stack Overflow works.